# How to assign existing code to new button in java class?

Tags: java, android

I have a randomJoke code in my MainActivity class basically telling my app to display a string everytime a button is clicked. Within the joke view I'm trying to create a function to do the same thing, except with a button WITHIN the joke view. So the user doesn't have to go back to the main page when they want another joke. Instead, they can just click a button on the jokes view. What should I add after "onClicK" to tell the app to do the same function as my randomJoke code (which is in the same activity class).   Thanks!!

My code so far is this:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);

    setupJokeButton();


}

private void setupJokeButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button JokeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextjoke);

    JokeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        }
    });
```

My randomJoke code looks like this:

```
public void randomJoke (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); 
    Random rand = new Random();
    int lowerBound = 1, upperBound = 83; //HERE IS WHERE YOU ADD THE HIGHEST NUMBER OF JOKES THERE IS
    int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(upperBound - lowerBound + 1) + lowerBound;
    String jokeNumber = "joke" + String.valueOf(randomNumber);
    String mess = getResources().getString(getStringResourcePath(getApplicationContext(),jokeNumber));
    //String jokeNumber = "joke" + String.valueOf(iteration);
    //iteration += 1;
    //String mess = getResources().getString(getStringResourcePath(getApplicationContext(), jokeNumber));
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, mess);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, you could do this

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        randomJoke(v);
```

Since `randomJoke()` just takes a `View` as its parameter you just call the method and send the `View` or `Button` that was clicked.